# How to get the length of the nested array object child length jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to get the length of the nested array object child length. I have tried to get the length but facing an issue, my array is getting override with the new value instead of pushing it to the existing array.

Array Object Example:

```
sDataArray = [Array[10], Array[9], Array[8]]
```

Now I want to calculate the length of the inner array length and push the data to the new array.

Expected Output:
`[Obj1, Obj2, Obj3,.....]`

This is what I tried:

```
var sDataTemp = [], sDataLength=0;
for(var j = 0; j < sDataArray.length; j++){
    sDataTemp = sDataArray[j];
}
sDataLength = sDataArray.length;
```

Comment: I guess you're looking for Array's [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Comment: @ hindmost : I tried, but doesn't work

Comment: What should `sDataTemp` contain?

Comment: the question is completely unclear about your expect output requirements - they don't correspond to your sample input.  Did you just want a new array that contains the length of the original nested arrays (e.g. `[10, 9, 8]`) ?

Comment: @M-S I don't see here what you've tried with `reduce`

Comment: @hindmost `reduce` is typically used to _aggregate_ data, and there's no sign in the question of that being needed.

Comment: @Alnitak It's very hard to understand (at least to me) from the question what the OP exactly needed

Comment: @hindmost hard indeed, hence my earlier comment, but in most cases if it's "array in, array out", then `map` is the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want an array of the lengths of the original arrays:

```
var lengths = sDataArray.map(function(a) {
    return a.length;
});
```

and that would produce `[10, 9, 8]` given your sample data.